# Timer function in initstate flutter causing a problem and changing the page information

Tags: flutter, timer, state, init, state-management

I am facing a problem in order details page. The page contains a timer function to call fetchOrderDetails after every 10 seconds to get current status of the order, but the problem is that page sometimes shows wrong information of any order (order number, etc automaitcally changes), it mostly happens when placing multiple orders at a time, the order number on this page automatically changing after every few seconds, then goes back to previous order number, then again shows new order number. I want to show order details of a single order number. Can anyone please help?  this is my initstate code `

```
@override
  void initState() {
    language =
        Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).appLanguage == "en_US"
            ? Languages.English
            : Languages.Arabic;
    getDineIn();
    getDelivery();
    getAuthToken().then((value) {
      Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .getProfileDetails(authToken);
    }).then((value) {
      userId = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).userId;
    }).then((value) {
      //from here
  // print("this is the order current status" +
  //     Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
  //         .orderCurrentStatus);

  // Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
  //     .getOrderDetails(
  //         token: authToken, userId: userId, orderNumber: widget.orderNumber)
  fetchOrderDetails(widget.orderNumber)
      .then((value) {
        setState(() {});
        Provider.of<RestaurantProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .getVenueData(
                venueId: Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .restaurantId,
                language: language == Languages.English ? 'eng' : 'ar');
        orderDateAndTime =
            Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
                .orderDateTime;
      })
      .then((value) => dateTime = DateTime.parse(orderDateAndTime))
      .then((value) {
        // formattedDate = DateFormat("E, dd MMMM, yyyy").format(dateTime);
        initializeDateFormatting("en_US", null).then((_) {
          var formatted = language == Languages.English
              ? DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd('en_US')
              : DateFormat.yMMMEd('ar_SA');
          print(formatted.locale);
          String format = formatted.format(dateTime);
          formattedDate = format;
          print(formatted);
        });
      });
  itemDetails =
      Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false).orderItemDetails;
  _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
    fetchOrderDetails(widget.orderNumber);
  });
  //to here
});

// Provider.of<RestaurantProvider>(context, listen: false)
//     .getVenueTimings(
//         branchId: '2',
//         language: language == Languages.English ? 'eng' : 'ar')
//     .then((value) {
// timingData =
//         Provider.of<RestaurantProvider>(context, listen: false).vt
// );
// });

Future.delayed(
  const Duration(seconds: 8),
  () {
    final orderCurrentStatus =
        Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .orderCurrentStatus;
    final isRated =
        Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false).isRated;
    print("current status" + orderCurrentStatus);
    if (orderCurrentStatus == 'completed' && isRated == "0"
        // &&
        // !widget.pastOrder
        ) ratingsBottomSheet(context, '1');
  },
);
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
  }`
```

the problem lies in this code of initstate, because when I commented this part, it didn't showed the bug (but also order status not changed)

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
    fetchOrderDetails(widget.orderNumber);
  });
```

this is dispose method

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // cancel the timer when the page is disposed to avoid memory leaks
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

this is didchangedependency code

```
      @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

      // Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
      //     .getOrderDetails(
      //         token: authToken, userId: userId, orderNumber: widget.orderNumber)
      fetchOrderDetails(widget.orderNumber).then((value) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 700), () {
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = false;
          });
          itemDetails = Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
              .orderItemDetails;
        });
      });
      // Provider.of<RestaurantProvider>(context, listen: false)
    }
    _isInit = false;

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

and this is fetch order details code that is called after regular intervals to check order status

```
  Future<void> fetchOrderDetails(String orderNumber) async {
await Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false).getOrderDetails(
    token: authToken, userId: userId, orderNumber: orderNumber);
  }
```

I would be grateful if someone supports to resolve this issue.